# Where to write nicht

Tags: negation

I use to always write *nicht* at the end of a sentence when I have to negate something

- As much as possible at the end of the phrase.

*Sie fanden den Schlüssel gestern nicht.*

- But I learnt that sometimes it has to be ahead the second part of the verb:

*Sie will nicht arbeiten.*

*Es fiel ihm nicht auf*

- Or even before an attribute of a subject:

*Wir freunen uns nicht auf den Abend*

- And even sometimes ahead an item if the negation is on it only.

*Er liest nicht die Zeitung*

---

I understand that **nicht** can't be at the end of a sentence when we have trennbare Verben:

*Er sieht jetzt nicht fern*

But why can't we have it at the end here for instance:

*Ich muss diesen Termin absagen.* Which becomes *Ich muss diesen Termin nicht absagen.*

And not *Ich muss diesen Termin absagen nicht.*

**Therefore, what is the rule to know where to write the negation in a sentence?**

Comment: Stick to English, its often the same. *I must cancel the appointment not* sounds weird. *He is reading the paper not*, *He did not notice*

Comment: @Alex: This is not really helpful for someone whose native language isn’t English.

Comment: @chirlu *is English not... :D